# What if I disagree with the closing of another person's question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/36050/is-it-needed-to-connect-all-pages-together-or-let-the-browsers-back-and-forward) was recently closed because it was thought to be a duplicate of "[Do users understand the browser back button?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7909/do-users-understand-the-browser-back-button)". In my comment I explained why I disagree: there are situations where a back button may not be present.

What do to in this situation? Should I edit the question to make it clear that it's not a duplicate? Please note that this is **not my question**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That question could just as equally been closed as being Not A Real Question, as the OP wasn't really asking anything in particular, and even though that was pointed out to the OP in a (up voted) comment they made no improvements to it. A reasonably similar duplicate was found to link it to so the question wasnt totally wasted, but really it's quite a poor question.

As per the FAQ:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

So that question doesn't really match that primary criteria.

However, in answer to your actual question about what you can do if you think it deserves to be reopened, you can:

1. Cast a reopen vote on it, although you'd need [3000 reputation to do so](https://ux.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions) so that's not really an option for you currently, although give it time.
2. Edit the question so that it is more answerable and unique. This will automatically add it to the reopen review queue so anyone with 3000 rep can see that it is flagged for reopening and can decide for themselves if it's suitable for reopening.
3. Flag it for moderator attention and state the reasoning for why it should be reopened. - this would only be seen and dealt with by moderators though, so their decisions would be final, and as a mod myself I wouldn't vote to reopen the question in its current state for they reasons stated above, although I can't speak for the other mods, Rahul or BenBrocka.

So I suggest option 2. See if you can make it a unique non-duplicate and answerable question and let the community device if it's worth reopening.